# Can't optain first value of an Get-CMDeploymentType Objcet/Array

Tags: powershell, sccm

I have a large Script that creats an Application in SCCM. One part of that script is to add the Supercedence of an Application

Due to the fact that searching for the possible Supercedence takes kinda long, i run this in a Background Job

```
Script-Block for Background Job $Super_func1

#$SSeed has a Part of an App Name String that is optained from the Start-job Argument

$appoldname = Get-CMApplication | where-object {$_.LocalizedDisplayName -like "*$SSeed*" } | select-object-first 1 -Property LocalizedDisplayName
Get-CMDeploymentType -ApplicationName $appoldname.LocalizedDisplayName
```

i start this as followed

```
$job = @()
$job += Start-Job -ArgumentList @($AppSupersedence) -ScriptBlock $Super_func1
```

after waiting for the job to finish i receive the job and want to access the AppModelName's first entry
and with that info i want to run a Get-CMApplication -ModelName $Modelname
It is possible that the Application has more then one Result (two Deploymenttypes) so that AppModelName has more then one Value.

```
Wait-Job -job $job  | Out-Null

$deployment23 = receive-job -job $job -keep
```

But i can only access the first value with a foreach loop.
that seems strange to me... so i guess i am doing something stupidly wrong

```
#this does not work
 $result23 = Get-CMApplication -ModelName $deployment23.AppModelName(0) --> Error
#This does not work
 $arrayresultme = $deployment23.AppModelName(0) --> Error
#This does work
 foreach ($Modelname in $deployment23.AppModelName){
    $result23 = ""
    $result23 = Get-CMApplication -ModelName $Modelname
    break
 }
```

The error that i get is:

Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.IResultObject#SMS_DeploymentType] does not contain a method named "AppModelName".

any hint on why i have to use the foreach would be appreciated

Comment: Use square brackets to retrieve a value of an array `Get-CMApplication -ModelName $deployment23.AppModelName[0]`

Comment: oh god... thank you. Why did i not think about it... now it works... How can i mark this question as answered?

Comment: I have created this as an answer could you please mark it as correct. The question will still remain as it is so that it allows people to find it if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell using standard brackets will usually attempt to call a method/function.

To retrieve a value from an array you need to use square brackets as shown below:

```
Get-CMApplication -ModelName $deployment23.AppModelName[0]
```